# Why do we say azure functions is a serverless compute service

Tags: azure, cloud

Please help me understand why we say azure functions is a serverless compute service. It does require cloud to host it and run. Cloud is also a server still why we are saying it is serverless?

Comment: https://www.winwire.com/serverless-computing-azure-functions/ this may help

Answer (score 2):

> Serverless computing does not mean that servers are out of the picture. Servers are very much required, just like they have been for all these years, or else, where will your code run. The reason why the phrase was coined is that as a developer, you do not need to worry about what server your code runs on. In fact, you do not know which server it eventually runs on. Once your code is deployed, Azure assigns the responsibility of executing the code to the next available server. What Azure ensures, and what is ultimately important for you, is that your code will execute whenever required.

Ref: [Serverless Computing with Azure Functions](https://www.winwire.com/serverless-computing-azure-functions/)

Hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

To get a better idea this is how we evolved. Cloud providers are making sure we should only worry about the business logic but nothing else.

**IaaS (Infrastructure as a service)**

You get a running VM somewhere in the data centre but you are required to maintain everything. From Deployment to patching your VMs or anything running on the VM.

**PaaS(Platform as a service)**

You are not longer required to maintain platForm but you are still responsible to manage your server in terms of load balancing etc.

**FaaS(Function as a service)**

Servers are abstracted from you . You are only required to maintain your code without worrying about what's under the hood or how to load balance your servers. It's then cloud provider responsibility to package your code and run it for you.  But servers are still there.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the official [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/solutions/serverless/) of Azure Serverless computing service, Azure Functions can be defined as;

> Azure Functions is a serverless compute service that enables you to run code on-demand without having to explicitly provision or manage infrastructure. Use Azure Functions to run a script or piece of code in response to a variety of events.
>
> Azure Functions is an event driven, compute-on-demand experience that
>   extends the existing Azure application platform with capabilities to
>   implement code triggered by events occurring in virtually any Azure or
>   3rd party service as well as on-premises systems. Azure Functions
>   allows developers to take action by connecting to data sources or
>   messaging solutions, thus making it easy to process and react to
>   events. Azure Functions scale based on demand and you pay only for the
>   resources you consume.

Here the serverless compute service is like a metaphor which implies, the end user doesn't need to manage the servers or infrastructure to run the applications over the Azure and can spend time to focus on managing and improving the business logic.

Few more points to consider,

- Serverless in Azure builds on an open-source foundation, the core of
  which is Azure Functions, an event-driven compute experience and [open
  source project](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions). Community contributions include support for new
  languages, integrations and deployment targets.
- Azure Functions can be used on-premises, in hybrid environments such as Azure Stack, on IoT Edge devices and deployed on top of orchestrators such as Kubernetes – as well as in other clouds.
- They enable faster time to market with lower infrastructure and operating costs.

Answer (score 0):

There are heaps of definition of serverless which you can easily google. But I will share my understanding anyways.

`1. It does require cloud to host it and run.`
You are correct with this. But anything on Cloud requires Cloud, doesn't it? Azure being one of the cloud providers consists of hundreds of services to cater to different needs people are after from using Cloud.

`2. Cloud is also a server still why we are saying is serverless`
This is not quite right. Cloud is different from a server. Server is a physical box sitting somewhere. With hundreds of thousands of servers all over the world, Cloud hosts all sorts of different services on these servers.

The reason we say Functions are serverless is that the infrastructure of hosting a Function is abstracted away from devs. It is still deployed to some servers but Azure is responsible for all the resource managing, configuration, load balancing, scaling and networking etc. It allows developers to focus primarily on their code, not having to worry about servers.